# Calling iterator from another function in python

Tags: python, function, class, iterator

Let's say i have a list of lists.
i want to iterate through every index in every list, and use it in another func.
So:

```
def func_a(self):
    for i in range(len(big_list)):
        current_list = big_list[i]
            for j in range(len(current_list):
                char_iter = iter(current_list)

def func_b(self):
    <<here i want to use the next char from iter>>
    <<how do i do it>>
```

Things I have tried:

- next(func) -> Error
- next(char_iter) - > Last Char

note:
i write this funcs in a class.

Comment: So what you want func_a to do is just iterate through everything and the func_b will use each value coming out of func_a?

Comment: Note that `for i in range(len(big_list)):   current_list = big_list[i]` is a poor way to do iteration.  Much better to do `for current_list in big_list`

Answer (score 3):

Not entirely sure what you are asking. As I understand the question, you want `func_a` to iterate though all the elements in all the nested lists, and make it so that other functions (particularly `func_b`) can reuse those.

In this case, you should loop through the lists and `yield` the chars, making `func_a` a generator function.

```
def func_a(self):
    for current_list in big_list:
        for char in current_list:
            yield char
```

You can then use it like this in `func_b`

```
def func_b(self):
    for char in func_a():
        print char
```

or using `next`:

```
def func_b(self):
    gen = func_a()
    print next(gen)
    print next(gen)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the basic idea.  Give more clarification if it's not enough.

```
big_list = [[1,2,3],[3,4]]

def func_a():
    for current_list in big_list:
        for value in current_list:
            yield value

y = func_a()


for x in y:
    print x
    if x>2:
        break

print 'broke'
for x in y:
    print x
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def func_a(self):
    return [j for i in big_list for j in i]

def func_b(self):
    flattened_big_list = func_a()
```

Comment: here func_a actually creates the entire list.  I don't think that's what OP wants.

Comment: You can change those outer `[...]` to `(...)` to make it a generator.

Comment: @Joel Maybe... but its just such a nice one-liner you can do with Python list comprehensions I just had to show it off... :)

Comment: @tobias_k ah, right! But to be honest, if you really want to iterate, a generator with ``for ... for ... yield`` as suggested by others is easier to read.

Comment: @Joel made my case of list-comprehension-based list flattening semantically more sensible

Answer (score 0):

You should not use index-based access, Python works best if you always just iterate, as it allows for lazy evaluation, as well as processing streams instead of random access containers.

I suggest using a generator:

```
def g(big_list):
    # no need for complicated indexing
    for current_list in big_list:
        # again, no need for index-based access
        for char in current_list:
            yield char


for char in g(the_big_list):
    func_b(char)
```